# Django formset validation: automatically fix form validation errors

Tags: django, django-forms

In an my model, I've the following

```
--- models.py ---
class A(models.Model):
   my_Bs = models.ManyToManyField('B', through='AlinksB')
   ...

class B(models.Model):
   ...

class AlinksB(models.Model):
   my_A = models.ForeignKey(A)
   my_B = models.models.ForeignKey(B)
   order = models.IntegerField()
```

So is the corresponding admin (A admin view has an inline to link B instances, and I prepared the required to custom this inline's formset and forms):

```
--- admin.py ---
class AlinksBInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = AlinksB

class AlinksBInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet): # there also is a BaseModelFormset
   form = AlinksBInlineForm

class AlinksBInline(admin.TabularInline):
   formset = AlinksBInlineFormset
   model = AlinksB

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = AForm
   inlines = (AlinksBInline,)
   ...

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
```

Now to custom the forms validation, nothing difficult: just override the "clean" method of the form object. If you want many different forms in the formset, I think you just have to change some manually in the "**init**" method of the formset. But what about programatically validating all the forms when we clean the formset, and that only under some conditions.

In my case: how to automatically set the "order" field (in the inline of A admin view) with an autoincrement if all the orders (inline rows to remove excluded) are empty ?!

Answer (score 3):

I just spent a lot of time Googling about trying to perform automatic form cleaning during a formset validation in Django Framework. After a few days a couldn't figure a solution so I started looking right into Django's source code to see how work fields, widgets, forms and formsets.

Here is what I understood:

-All the data POSTed by the user when he submits the formset it stored in the "**data**" attribute of the formset. This attribute is very ugly and cannot be directly used.
- The form is just a wrapper for fields (it calls all the fields' clean methods and fill error buffers, and only a few more)

-The form fields have a widget. This widget allow getting back the field's **raw value** from the "data" attribute of the formset

```
form.add_prefix('field name') # returns the 'field prefix', the key of formset.data used to retrieve the field's raw value
form.fields['field name'].widget.value_from_datadict(form.data, form.files, 'field prefix') # returns the raw value
```

-The form fields also have a method to transform the raw value into a right python value (in my case: order is an integer, or None if the field has been left empty)

```
form.fields['field name'].to_python(raw_value) # returns a value with the right type
```

-You can change the value of one of the fields from the formset with the following code

```
form.data.__setitem__('field prefix', value) # code to update an iterable knowing the key to change
```

-Once you have modified the fields value, you can call the "**full_clean**" method of the forms to retry cleaning them (this will remove the previous errors).

-Once you have validated again the forms, you can retry validating the formset with its "**full_clean**" method too. But take care to avoid infinite loops

-The forms clean data can only be used has a read-only data, to add more error messages in the form or the formset

An other solution would be to manually change  the "form.clean_data" attribute, and clean the formset.errors and all the form.errors

Hope it could help somebody in the same situation as me !

Ricola3D